# Hangs on browser startup

Tags: puppeteer-sharp

I run the software in multiple threads and after it finishes, the browser restarts and repeats the cycle. I noticed that sometimes they can just "disappear", stop working. By adding output to the console in different places I realized that the problem occurs when the browser starts.

```
static public PuppeteerExtraSharp.PuppeteerExtra extra = new();
...
var languagesSettings = new PuppeteerExtraSharp.Plugins.ExtraStealth.Evasions.StealthLanguagesOptions("en-US");
extra.Use(new PuppeteerExtraSharp.Plugins.ExtraStealth.StealthPlugin(languagesSettings));

...
Console.WriteLine($"#{num} - browser starting...");
await using var browser = await extra.LaunchAsync(opt);
Console.WriteLine($"#{num} - browser started");
...
```

- num is number of threads

The problem can occur after as few as 10 restarts or as many as 100. In addition, the browser itself starts, but after starting I no longer get output to the console and the browser just idles.